# How to omit the string inside nested round bracket using XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a node

```
<statement> 
     SORBITOL, ARÔMES ARTIFICIELS, DIOXYDE DE SILICIUM, ASPARTAME (05 mg / PIECE (01 g)), ACESULFAME-POTASSIUM (03 mg / PIECE (01 g)), STEARATE DE MAGNESIUM. L'ASPARTAME CONTIENT DE LA PHENYLALANINE.
</statement>
```

And i need to transform this to:

```
<statement>SORBITOL, ARÔMES ARTIFICIELS, DIOXYDE DE SILICIUM, ASPARTAME , ACESULFAME-POTASSIUM , STEARATE DE MAGNESIUM. L'ASPARTAME CONTIENT DE LA PHENYLALANINE.</statement>
```

Therefore i need a function that will extract all the text except string inside round bracket recursively so that if more nesting of round bracket present the function should return the string by omitting the bracket and the sting inside bracket. I need it in XSLT version 1.0.

Comment: and what you have tried so far?

Comment: `<xsl:template name="removeRoundBracket">
    <xsl:param name="string1"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($string1,'(')">
            <xsl:call-template name="removeRoundBracket">
               <xsl:with-param name="string1" select="concat(normalize-space(substring-before($string1,'(')), ' ', normalize-space(substring-after($string1,')')))" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>`

Comment: Hi have tried the above template it work fine if their is no nesting of round bracket.Can you please help to get it solved.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="statement">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:call-template name="removeRoundBracket">
                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="removeRoundBracket">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(substring-before($data, ')'), '(')">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($data, '(')"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="removeRoundBracket">
                    <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring-after($data, ')')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($data, ')')">
                <xsl:call-template name="removeRoundBracket">
                    <xsl:with-param name="data" select="substring-after($data, ')')"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$data"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See transformation at http://xsltransform.net/93nvfck

**OUTPUT**

```
<statement>SORBITOL, ARÔMES ARTIFICIELS, DIOXYDE DE SILICIUM, ASPARTAME , ACESULFAME-POTASSIUM , STEARATE DE MAGNESIUM. L'ASPARTAME CONTIENT DE LA PHENYLALANINE.</statement>
```

Comment: Excellent work!The above solution work for me the only the changes i have made is i have concat the entire result for further processing.Thank much for your answer.